# Firebase hosting static file serve very slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My user took 1.6 min to download a 900KB static file from firebase hosting.

May I know is there any way to optimize this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for Doug Stevenson on pointing out, the main reason for slow TTFB and content download speed is because Fastly CDN performs poorly in my country (Malaysia). Switched to Cloudflare to resolve the problem.

The image below shows that test on [Cloud Harmony](http://cloudharmony.com/), Fastly CDN has a really bad result especially downlink for > 256KB
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There really is no way to optimize the time it takes for Firebase Hosting to serve static content, other than taking steps to reduce the amount of data to transfer (maybe compressing it differently), or splitting the data among more than one concurrent request.

It will take as long as it takes to transfer the content the user.  The user's internet connection speed makes a huge difference, and if their connection is slow, that situation can't be improved.

Comment: This issue happens from time to time, even with a good network. And from the image, 12s for TTFB is unreasonable, will it possibly issue with firebase hosting or CDN cache miss? My user location is in Malaysia and the firebase hosting server is at another side of the earth.

Comment: Firebase Hosting uses a worldwide CDN (the product called "Fastly") that caches data that's closer to the user than the source of the data.  A CDN cache miss would likely take more time than a local cache hit.  Custom HTTP response headers will indicate if there was a cache hit or miss.  But there's not much you can do to change the behavior of the CDN for static content.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Can I conclude that the high FFTB and slow content download is most probably due to the firebase CDN issue?

Comment: The CDN is run by Fastly, not Firebase.  Fastly sits in front of the core Firebase Hosting service.  If there was a cache hit, it was delivered by Fastly.  If there was a cache miss, it was delivered by Firebase via the CDN.  https://www.fastly.com/

Comment: See also documentation for Firebase subprocessors.  https://firebase.google.com/terms/subprocessors

Comment: understand, I will wait for the next incident happen, and check the header to verify that cache is being used or not. Then I can narrow down the problem to 1) fastly CDN has slow content delivery, 2) firebase static content not being cached by Fastly CDN. As as your suggest, I should also chunk my vendor.js so that user can get the first view as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm not so sure that Fastly will deliver anything in a chunked fashion.